# PLC Object Oriented Programming - Using methods

Tags: oop, plc, structured-text

I'm writing a program for a Schneider PLC using structured text, and I'm trying to do it using object oriented programming.

Being a newbie in PLC programming, I wrote a simple test program such a this:

```
okFlag:=myObject.aMethod();
IF okFlag THEN
   // it's ok, go on
ELSE
  //  error handling
END_IF
```

`aMethod` must perform some operations, wait for the result (there is a "time-out" check to avoid deadlocks) and return TRUE or FALSE

This is what I expected during program execution

1) when the `okFlag:=myObject.aMethod();` is reached, the code inside `aMethod` is executed until a result is returned. When I say "executed" I mean that in the next scan cycle the execution of `aMethod`continues from the point it had reached before.

2) the result of method calling is checked and the main flow of the program is executed

and this is what happens:

1) `aMethod` is executed but the program flow continues. That is, when it reaches the end of `aMethod` a value it's returned, even if the events that `aMethod` should wait for are still executing.

2) on the next cycle, `aMethod` is called again and restarts from the beginning

This is the first solution I found:

```
VAR_STATIC
   imBusy: BOOL
END_VAR 

METHOD aMethod: INT;

IF NOT(imBusy) THEN
  imBusy:=FALSE;
  aMethod:=-1; // result of method while in progress
ELSE
  aMethod:=-1;         
  <rest of code. If everything is ok, the result is 0, otherwise is 1>
END_IF
imBusy:=aMethod<0;
```

and the main program:

```
CASE (myObject.aMethod()) OF
  0: // it's ok, go on
  1: //  error handling
ELSE
    // still executing...
END_CASE
```

and this seems to work, but I don't know if it's the right approach.

There are some libraries from Schneider which use methods that return boolean and seem to work as I expected in my program. That is: when the cycle reaches the call to method for the first time the program flow is "deviated" somehow so that in the next cycle it enters again the method until it's finished. It's there a way to have this behaviour ?

Comment: are you using Somachine or Unity?

Comment: SoMachine, 4.1 version

Answer (score 2):

generally OOP isn't the approach that people would take when using IEC61131 languages. Your best bet is probably to implement your code as a state machine. I've used this approach in the past as a way of simplifying a complex sequence so that it is easier for plant maintainers to interpret.

Typically what I would recommend if you are going to take this approach is to try to segregate your state machine itself from your working code; you can implement a state machine of X steps, and then have your working code reference the statemachine step.

A simple example might look like:

```
stepNo := 0;
IF (start AND stepNo = 0) THEN
    StepNo = 1;
END_IF;

(* there's a shortcut unity operation for resetting this array to zeroes which is faster, but I can't remember it off the top of my head... *)
ActiveStepArray := BlankStepArray;

IF stepNo > 0 THEN
  IF StepComplete[stepNo] THEN
      stepNo := stepNo +1;
  END_IF;

  ActiveStepArray[stepNo] := true;
END_IF;
```

Then in other code sections you can put...

```
IF ActiveStep[1] THEN
   (* Do something *)

   StepComplete[1] := true;
END_IF;

IF ActiveStep[2] THEN
   (* Do Something *)
   StepComplete[2] := true;
END_IF;

(* etc *)
```

The nice thing about this approach is that you can actually put all of the state machine code (including jumps, resets etc) into a DFB, test it and then shelve it, and then just use the active step, step complete, and any other inputs you require.

Your code is still always going to execute an entire section of logic, but if you really want to avoid that then you'll have to use a lot of IF statements, which will impede readability.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use SFC it makes your live easier in many cases, since it is state machine language itself. Do subprogram, wait condition do another .. rince and repeat. :)

Don't hang just for ST, the other IEC languages are better in some other tasks and keep thing as clear as possible. There should be not so much "this is my cake" mentality on the industrial PLC programming circles as it is on the many other programming fields, since application timeline can be 40 years and you left the firm 20 years ago to better job and programs are almost always location/customer or atleast hardware specific.

http://www.automation.com/pdf_articles/IEC_Programming_Thayer_L.pdf

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of possible approaches on how to do object-oriented programming in Structured Text:

**1.** It is possible to write mostly object-oriented applications in any programming language:

- Define a structure, containing all fields of your object.
- Now this structure can be the first parameter of your method, substituting for **this** or **self**.
- Use some naming convention like an agreed-on prefix to mark all "methods" as belonging to your class (`QM_AddToQueue`, `QM_RemoveFromQueue`, etc).

This results in the code of course somewhat more bulky than in modern C++ but completely survivable. If there are too many objects, group them into packages.

If polymorphism is required (that is not always the case but it might be something like shared queue for different events), the "object structure" can contain fields for all cases and enum tag to differentiate of what type it actually is. This works well enough if the number of fields is small and many are shared.

**2.** Alternatively, you can see a Function Block as an object in the Structured Text. You can nicely define strictly internal fields and read only properties (VAR_OUTPUT).

This works well with the only drawback that your object can only have ... a single method! (a call of the function block). But there are cases when this is actually enough or you can always add the enum specifying the exact action to take.